# Microsoft Access: many tables and keys

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm not much of an database expert, and our company wants to optimize our database usage if it's possible. The problem is; we have many tables that create a long road to the correct information, like this:

```
tblPIECES -> tblMATERIAL -> tblTEMPERATURES
```

tblPIECES has a unique id, which is connected to tblMATERIAL's same unique id. tblMATERIAL includes many columns, which include new keys and relations to other tables, such as tblTEMPERATURES. So the key is different than before, but the keys are related to each other.

The question is; is there any way to shorten the select command for this kind of situation?
Now I need to:

1. Select temperaID from tblMATERIAL where pieceID is.. pieceID
2. Select maxtemperature from tblTEMPERATURES where temperaId is temperaID

This is how I access the temperature information. We use relationships to delete things, like: if you remove the piecesID, it also removes the materials references to that key, and then they are removed from temperatures due to material removal.

Is there any shorter reference to all temperatures which are connected to a given pieceID's temperaID?

Some of the items contain only one match, some contain multiple items while using the same key. The problem here is the key which changes between these tables, and we need an additional query to get it first.

We also thought about inner joining, and it was one of the answers to this problem, but it's sometimes too heavy of a command since somethimes we have more than 3+ tables linked together this way, and the key changes.

They are hardly to change the MS ACCESS database's structure.

Comment: Your struture is fine, you need to learn to use joins. And three plus tables is nothing for a proeprly indexed database. I regularly join to 15-20 multiple millino record tables.

Comment: Agree with HLGEM.  "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler." — Dr. Albert Einstein

Comment: I agree with the others, you'll need to learn about LEFT and INNER JOINS in order to really use the database. The current structure sounds as if it's properly normalized, which is a big asset, and not something to restructure. Now if you had a massive (100+ table) database, you could think about denormalizing some of them.

Comment: But still: is there a possibility to refer to the "maxtemperature" directly, even though the key changes? I understand that it is possible with the same key (pieceID), but the different key changes everything.
The database know the route to all that data, because they're linked with relations. And if I remove the pieceID, all the temperature datas related to that pieceID will also be deleted with it.
Is it possible to use this same "link" or "route" which access know to directly refer to the "maxtemperature" with the only given pieceid? Without knowing the further tablenames, except pieceID's.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like proper data normalization to me.  It also sounds like your tables are in proper relationships, and those relationships enforce referrential integrity.  In short; this sounds like a model database.  Unfortunately, if you want to keep data in its optimal format, querying it does require a little work.  However, once you set up a few basic queries, all future queries should only be pointing to these "base" queries and not to tables.

Comment: Agree.  Your company's goals are going to require skill at solid beginner's level, at least.  For most of us, Excel is the precedent to learning Access; the "curve" for Access is much steeper, but it's a lot of fun.  If you're the one who pushes this forward, you will gain core understanding to enrich other pursuits.  Sounds grandiose, but that's my experience.